# Grover's search on cryptographic hash functions - how can we build the oracle?

Tags: quantum-computing

Let's say I'd like to search a database and I have a function $f$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for all incorrect entries and $f(x) = 1$ for all target entries.

The crux of Grover's search seems to be that there exists a way to construct a quantum operator $\hat{f}$ in a way that it takes a superposition of states as input and adds a phase only to the target elements from the superposition.

What guarantee do we have that such a construction exists? For example, if I take a classical hashing function, how do I go about building the quantum equivalent that is able to simultaneously evaluate multiple inputs and assign the phase only to those inputs that fall below some target threshold?

Comment: See this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/59728/how-is-the-oracle-function-for-grovers-search-algorithm-obtained?rq=1.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  I think the duplicate (https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50496/755) answers your question -- it describes how to implement the function in a quantum circuit -- but please check.  If not, please edit the question to clarify your question.  Thanks!